# Set focus on next Textfield

Tags: javafx-8, textfield, setfocus

I have some JavaFX TextFields that receives only one character. When typing this unique character the focus should move to the next Textfield control. Using Swing is easy (KeyboardFocusManager), but in JavaFX I have not found.

I really apreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's no built-in focus API in JavaFX: all you can do is call `requestFocus` on the next text field. You will have to code the logic to figure out which is the next one; depending on how you have things set up, that may be trivial or may be a pain. IIRC there's a feature request for a focus manager API.

Comment: Thank you James. I've read somewhere that Oracle's team responsible for JavaFX is working on an API to focus subsystem. Regards...